# Google calc - title of document containing a cell value

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Quick question, Im afraid it is not possible, but maybe...
I have multiple documents - spreadsheets. Each one is a copy of another, but there are different "products" in that documents. On a list of documents where I see titles, would be nice to see also a value from one specific cell in document ("Some title - 26,3%" - where 26,3% is a value from a specific cell). That value tells alot and it would make my work a bit easier.

If its not possible I'll make it manually.
Thanks for any sugestions.

Comment: Hi, It's possible using Google Apps Script.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, indicating the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `IMPORTRANGE` built-in function. You can find the documentation [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en).

For example: `=IMPORTRANGE("INSTERT_ID", "SPECIFY_RANGE")`.

Just change the `INSTERT_ID` to the `ID` of the spreadsheet you are trying to import data from, and the SPECIFY_RANGE to the range you want to import.